# react native app stay blank after implementing redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native, redux-persist

Everyone

i am trying to persist my store using redux-persist but after implementing it to my app.js, i get white screen, i looked for this error, and the only thing i could find was to purge the persistor in componentDidMount() and even that didn't work for me:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font } from 'expo';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import storeConfig from './config/store';
import RootNavigation from './navigation/RootNavigation';
import Splash from './screens/Splash'
const {persistor, store} = storeConfig();
```

> // normal code

```
render() {
if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete ) {
  return (
    <AppLoading
      startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
      onError={this._handleLoadingError}
      onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
    />
  );
} else {
  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<Splash /> } persistor={persistor}>
      <RootNavigation />
      </PersistGate>
      </Provider> 

  );
}
```

}

store.js :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import reducers from '../reducers';


const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
  };


const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = createStore(pReducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Hey, I used redux-persist@4.10.2 and it worked like a charm. since a lot of troubleshooting targeted that version. I hope this helps you.